# Error Adding AUTO_INCREMENT Column to Rails Model - MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I currently have an existing model, Document, that needs a new, auto-incrementing column. Unfortunately, I am getting errors during the migrate.

The steps I have taken are:

`ruby script/generate migration add_index_column_to_Document`

which properly generated the empty `.rb` titled

`20121220182429_add_index_column_to_document.rb`

Next, I edited the file to look like:

```
class AddIndexColumnToDocument < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute 'ALTER TABLE documents ADD index INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY'
  end

  def self.down
    execute 'ALTER TABLE documents DROP index'
  end
end
```

Then I executed the migration with `rake db:migrate` and got the following error:

```
==  AddIndexColumnToDocument: migrating =======================================
-- execute("ALTER TABLE documents ADD index INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY' at line 1: ALTER TABLE documents ADD index INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

The MySQL version, according to `apt-cache show mysql-server` is: **5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2**

Unfortunately for me, my SQL code matches that of all examples I can find online, so I am unsure as to why it is not working. Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the conventional 'id' as primary_key?  You might have an easier time later if you did...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the word 'index' which is reserved.  Even better, let Rails do it for you:

```
class AddIndexColumnToDocument < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :documents, :index, :primary_key
  end
end
```

Comment: Or better, don't use "index" at all, come up with a different name so that you don't have to backtick it every time you use it in an SQL snippet.

Comment: That was my comment above about using 'id'.  Presumably, if 'id' isn't good enough, then there is a requirement to use specifically 'index'.

Comment: I'm just saying that calling a column `index` in a relational database is just asking for trouble and an ugly mess. If you can't use `id` for whatever reason, `index` is still a bad choice for the name.

Comment: Indeed it is, I actually thought the OP was actually trying to make an INDEX auto-increment before reading it several times...

Comment: My apologies about the poor column name. Ill definitely rename it to something more logical/less confusing.